# PHPUnit throws error: \Drupal\Tests\DocumentElement class not found

Tags: 9, testing

I have added some phpunit tests to my custom module. When trying to run them in I get this error: `Class '\Drupal\Tests\DocumentElement' not found` I have copied core/phpunit.xml.dist to core/phpunit.xml and edited the URL and DB values but nothing else.

The command I'm running is `vendor/bin/phpunit -c web/core/phpunit.xml web/modules/contrib/my_module/`.

It seems that the classloader is not working. What have I missed?

I'm using drupal 9 and phpunit 9. I've also tried with phpunit 7 and 8 but I get the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this! The package [drupal/core-dev](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core-dev) is required.

```
composer require --dev drupal/core-dev
```

This installs the package as a development dependency.

Comment: Simple, but if you forgot about this as I did just now, can be frustrating!

Comment: composer require drupal/core-dev

Answer (score -1):

Drupal forgot to add few dependency libraries.

See you have these 2 libraries.

```
composer show symfony/phpunit-bridge 
composer show phpspec/prophecy-phpunit
```

If you don't please install.

I also noticed that following library also essential.

```
behat/mink
```

Comment: Those are dependencies for *drupal/core-dev*. If you need them, you need *drupal/core-dev*.